# Sort array of custom objects depending on dynamic criterias

Tags: arrays, swift, performance, sorting

Say we have the following Object, Priority & Requirement objects:

```
enum Priority: CaseIterable {
    case priorityA = "priority_a"
    case priorityB = "priority_b"
    case priorityC = "priority_c"
    case priorityD = "priority_d"
    case priorityE = "priority_e"
    case priorityF = "priority_f"
    case priorityG = "priority_g"
    ... 

    var weight: Int {
        switch self {
            ...
        }
    }
}

struct Object {
    let name: String
    let priorities: [Priority: Int]
}

enum RequirementBaseValue {
    case any
    case minimum(Int)
    case maximum(Int)
}

struct Requirement {
    let priority: Priority
    let baseValue: RequirementBaseValue
}
```

An example:

```
let requirementA = Requirement(priority: .priorityB, baseValue: .any)
let requirementB = Requirement(priority: .priorityC, baseValue: .minimum(100))
let requirements = [requirementA, requirementB]

let aPriorities =  [..., .priorityB: 0, .priorityC: 0, ... ]
let objectA = Object(name: "object_a", priorities: aPriorities)

let bPriorities = [..., .priorityB: 950, .priorityC: 210, ... ]
let objectB = Object(name: "object_b", priorities: bPriorities)

let cPriorities = [..., .priorityB: 950, .priorityC: 300, ... ]
let objectC = Object(name: "object_c", priorities: cPriorities)

let dPriorities = [..., .priorityB: 250, .priorityC: 101,  ... ]
let objectD = Object(name: "object_d", priorities: dPriorities)

let objects = [objectA, objectB, objectC, objectD]
```

The goal is to sort these objects:

```
let sortedObjects = objects.sorted(by: { ... })
```

For example, considering the weights of each priority is equal to 1, for the example above we would have:

```
print(sortedObjects)
// [objectC, objectB, objectD, objectA]
```

And a few details about how the sorting should be performed:

- If the requirement `baseValue` is set to `any`: the higher the `resultValue` the earlier it should appear in the sorted array.
- If the requirement value is either set to `minimum(Int)` or `maximum(Int)`: if the priority doesn't match the condition, the object should be filtered out from the array, otherwise the higher the `resultValue` the earlier it should appear in the sorted array.
- If an object's priorities dictionary doesn't contain a specific priority, we consider the `baseValue` for this priority to be equal to 0.
- The `resultValue` is obtained by multipying the weight property of a priority by the `baseValue` of the priority.
- Each object will usually have between 80 to 200 priorities (maximum will be n=`Priority.allCases.count`).
- The objects array will usually have between 3000 to 5000 elements so performance will be important.

I was thinking of doing something like this:

```
let sortedObjects = objects.sorted(by: { object in
   for requirement in requirements {
       let baseValue = object.priorities[requirement.priority] ?? 0
       let weight = requirement.priority.weight
       let resultValue = baseValue * weight
       ...
   } 
   return ...
}
```

But then I'm not sure how to return the boolean because there are multiple requirements & priorities for each object, and it's not just an AND or OR condition, but more of an else-if situation.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"...if the priority doesn't match the condition, the object should be filtered out from the array"

Looks like you're mixing two operations into one. The more straightforward way is to filter the array first and then sort it.

Something like this:

```swift
func isSatisfying(requirement: Requirement, object: Object) -> Bool {
    let value = object.priorities[requirement.priority] ?? 0
    switch requirement {
    case .any: return true
    case .minimum(let minValue): return value >= minValue
    case .maximum(let maxValue): return value <= maxValue
}

let filteredObjects = objects.filter { obj in
    // returns true if all requirements are satisfied
    return requirements.allSatisfy { req in
        return isSatisfying(requirement: req, object: obj)
    }
}
let sortedObjects = filteredObjects.sort { first, second in
    let firstResultValue = ...
    let secondResultValue = ...
    return firstResultValue >= secondResultValue
}
```

Comment: Thank you ! That sounds great. allSatisfy will be very useful here! However, for the last closure (sorting) I need to make the check on multiple criterias (dynamically, as I cannot know beforehand how many and which it will be), do you have any ideas on how it could work with this function? Unfortunately, in case of the sorting (last closure) the allSatisfy would not work because what I'm looking for is really a if ... else if ... and so on.

Comment: I think you should consider dividing complex sort function into smaller ones. On the whole for sorting function you have to calculate total weight for both elements and return true if the first one weights more.

So you need function, which calculates weight of element based on list of requirements. To do that you have to calculate weight for each requirement and sum them up.

Comment: So at the end you need a function that takes an element, a requirement and returns weight for that specific requirement. Then sum up weights for all requirements and compare two elements.